# Wave-Particle Duality in the Confinement of an Electron in a Box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, waves, schroedinger-equation, wave-particle-duality

[image]
According to the wave particle duality, one can say that an electron is both a wave and a particle. If we confine it in a box, it can only form standing waves at particular wavelengths, which leads to the quantization of energy. **When one draws the second excited state, do we mean to say that we want three antinodes and four nodes in the box?**

Are we talking about the same type of standing waves? Are the following formulas applicable:

$$\lambda=\frac{2L}{m}~?$$

Using it, I found for m=3, the second excited state, a wavelenth of $6*10^{-11}$ m. However, this does not work with the answer in my book. Apparently, the answer is 0.515 nm. **Are standing waves in this confinement the same type as the standing waves of strings for example?**

Comment: I agree with you. The wavelength of the $n = 3$ state is going to be of order $\tfrac{2}{3}$ times the size of the box. So I don't see how the answer can possible be 0.515nm. I wonder if there's a misprint and the box side should be 0.9nm. In that case you'd expect the answer to be about 0.6nm, which is in the right ball park.